# How to customize date format as 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss'?

Tags: angular, momentjs, mat-datepicker

**Returning Moment object instead of Date value in 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss' format**

I tried the following but getting moment object instead of Date. I searched a lot but none of them give me the solution.

```
import * as _moment from 'moment';
import { default as _rollupMoment } from 'moment';
const moment = _rollupMoment || _moment;

export const MY_FORMATS = {
    parse: {
        dateInput: 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss',
    },
    display: {
        dateInput: 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss',
        monthYearLabel: 'MMM YYYY',
        dateA11yLabel: 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss',
        monthYearA11yLabel: 'MMMM YYYY',
    },
};
```

I provided the format inside @Component decorator

```
@Component({
     providers: [
    {
      provide: DateAdapter,
      useClass: MomentDateAdapter,
      deps: [MAT_DATE_LOCALE, MAT_MOMENT_DATE_ADAPTER_OPTIONS]
    },
    { provide: MAT_DATE_FORMATS, useValue: MY_FORMATS },
  ]
})
```

Inside Class =>

```
 dateOfBirth: new FormControl();
```

Comment: what is the issue you are struggling with?

Comment: the best to understand is angular documentation itself. can you check the example Datepicker that uses Moment.js dates
https://stackblitz.com/angular/anxvgmnxjqv?file=src%2Fapp%2Fdatepicker-moment-example.ts

Comment: @noamsteiner I'm getting moment.js object instead of required date format

Comment: @GauravUpadhyay as your stackblitz example, we can see the date format in datepicket, but I'm telling about the return value

Comment: @Praveen RL -  it is not so much clear. either you should edit your question with exactly telling what is the problem and what is your expected with comments. if possible create a stackblitz.

Answer (score 0):

Add the below code in your application.

app.module.ts

```
 import { DateAdapter, MAT_DATE_FORMATS, MAT_DATE_LOCALE } from '@angular/material/core';
    import { MomentDateModule, MomentDateAdapter } from '@angular/material-moment-adapter';
    import { DatePipe } from '@angular/common';
    
    export const DateFormats = {
        parse: {
            dateInput: 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss',
        },
        display: {
            dateInput: 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss',
            monthYearLabel: 'MMM YYYY',
            dateA11yLabel: 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss',
            monthYearA11yLabel: 'MMMM YYYY',
        },
    };
    
    
    providers: [
        { provide: DateAdapter, useClass: MomentDateAdapter, deps: [MAT_DATE_LOCALE] },
        { provide: MAT_DATE_FORMATS, useValue: DateFormats }
        , DatePipe
    ],
```

***.components,ts**

```
dateOfBirth: new FormControl();
```

If you add the above code in your project correctly, you get all the mat date picker date value in this format YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm: ss

Comment: proper date can be get when I used this in stackblitz application, but in another existing application it returning Moment object instead of Date value

Comment: bro dob date YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm: ss intha formate la return pananuma. db la store panrahuku

Answer (score 0):

try this code.

```
import { DatePipe, formatDate } from '@angular/common';
import { Component, OnInit, ElementRef, ViewChild, ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, FormControl, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

export class UserRegistrationComponent implements OnInit {
dateOfBirth: new FormControl();

constructor(private datePipe: DatePipe){

}

save(){
    this.datePipe.transform(this.dateOfBirth.value, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
}
}
```

Comment: I know this bro, but I need the date value from mat-datepicker without any method in .ts file, because I'm using so much of date fields inside a form, so transforming every field is not seems to be the best.

Comment: Bro, As of my knowledge without the date transform we can't convert the date. If you do it in please let share with me

Comment: Sorry I missed something in previous comment, I need the date date value from datepicker using the method used in question. Kindly refer this stackblitz app - select a date , submit and check it in console: 
https://angular-mat-datepicker-custom-format.stackblitz.io/